# Angular 2 routing displays both the component

Tags: angular, routes

I have a login component and  mainpage component in  angular 2. when i logged in  and try to navigate to main page, both  login and mainpage component are coming in same page.

my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { Appmainpage }  from './mainpage.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


const appRoutes: Routes = [

   {path: 'login', component: AppComponent},
   { path: 'mainpage', component: Appmainpage}


 ];

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, Appmainpage ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

my app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Login } from './login';
import { Router }  from '@angular/router';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `

  <router-outlet> </router-outlet>

  `,  
})


export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(public _router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute){} 
  model  = new Login(null, null)
  uname:any;
  pwd:any;
ulogin()
{
  if (this.model.uname == "NP13310" && this.model.pwd == "pandi")
{
console.log("sucess");
 this._router.navigate(['../mainpage'], { relativeTo: this.route});
}

}

 }
```

my  mainpage.component.ts which  displays the main page

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
@Component({

templateUrl: 'app/mainp.component.html'  
})
export class Appmainpage  {


 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AppComponent is the root of your app. It displays everything in the router-outlet. You should create an other component for Login.

Comment: Thanks tano.. if i create seperate component for login, then how i can display the login component as first page in my application ?

Comment: Thanks, its solved my issue. I put separate component for login. Once the root component gets loaded, i it to login component. Hence the login component comes as first page